# How can I see a list of Keywords with Goal progress for each?

Tags: google-analytics, keywords, google-ads, conversions, goal-tracking

I have created several goals in Google Analytics and I want to view the keywords we've bid on with the Conversion Rate for each Goal.

I've connected GA and Adwords. I can see the Goals but not by keyword.
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897976/how-to-know-which-keywords-convert-into-goals-in-google-analytics) but the instructions don't match the GA UI (maybe it's changed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a custom report as suggested by that answer on StackOverflow.  There is a report that does exactly what you want:

In the left hand list of reports, navigate to:

1. Acquisition
2. Keywords
3. Paid

This report lists your keywords.  By default it shows 10 but you can use the "Show rows" drop down to show up to 5000 of them at a time.

Your goal progress is the last three columns in the table under "Conversions" heading.   Select the goal that you are interested in from the drop down to get the stats about how well each keyword is performing towards that goal.